# How do I get my own Mapbox style to show up in a story map?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

I am using Mapbox to create a story map while following the instructions on this page: https://github.com/mapbox/storytelling. At Step 5 in the page, you can see where the style is added. I have created my own style which is rather simple. It keeps the base OpenStreetMap map but adds a polygon, point, and polyline layer. This style is added instead of the base Mapbox style and it does not show up when I load my html page. I know the problem is not my token as I have messed around with other styles and they were showing up in my html page. My style is published and it is public, so I am not really sure what I can do here.

Here is my Mapbox style URL: mapbox://styles/pakulu/clnatt1la07mk01qieiphcaeh.